# Vector spaces, theoretical question

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am having trouble to solve the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space. Show that:
>
> a) If $f,g \in V^{*}$ then there exists an $a \in K $ such that $ g = af$ if and only if $\ker(f)\subseteq \ker(g)$.
>
> b) Generalize part a).

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Is $V^*$ the dual of $V$?

Comment: I guess you're stuck somewhere in part a)? Where?

Comment: Yes, $V^{*}$ is the dual of $V$. I am not understand how i am going to use $ g= af$ to conclude the exercise....

Comment: For the first direction assume $f(x) = 0$ and use $g = af$ to show that $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: If $a = 0$ then both functionals are zero. If The statement is true and $a \ne 0$ then $Ker(f) \subseteq Ker(g)$ implies $g = af$ which implies $f = a^{-1}g$ since $K$ is a field. This in turn implies $Ker(g) \subseteq Ker(f)$. Are you sure this is true?

Comment: @Daron I believe its true, well it seems true. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Daron: It's true, $\ker f$ is either $V$ or a hyperplane.

Comment: @Daron If $a=0$, then $g=0$ and we could have $f$ be any non-zero functional.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to a):

Suppose that $g=af$.  Now, consider any $v\in\ker(f)$.  $g(v)=af(v)=a\cdot0=0$.  So, $v\in\ker(g)$.  Thus, $\ker(f)\subseteq \ker(g)$.

Suppose that $\ker(f)\subseteq \ker(g)$.

In the case that $g(v)=0: g(v)=0\cdot f(v)$.

Suppose then that $g$ is non-zero, and take $\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\}$ to be a basis of $ V-\ker(f)$.  Suppose (to derive a contradiction) that $g\neq af$.  Then there exist $a_1 \neq a_2$ such that $g(w_1)=a_1f(w_1)$ and $g(w_2)=a_2f(w_2)$.  Then 
$$
g(a_2f(w_2)\cdot w_1-a_1f(w_1)\cdot w_2)=0
$$
Thus, $a_2f(w_2)\cdot w_1-a_1f(w_1)\cdot w_2\in\ker(g)-\ker(f)$.  This is a contradiction of our premise.